# Time series analysis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing the visits on a website, I have two columns `ID` number and the `date` in the format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`.

I would like to get a data frame containing the time difference between any visit of a customer. I found how to get the numbers of visits using GROUPBY but I don't know for the rest.

Edit:

```
No.      IDs      date
 1      4678     2012-11-30 23:59:59
 2      4703     2012-11-30 23:59:23
 3      4678     2012-11-30 23:58:46
 4      5803     2012-11-30 23:58:19
 5      4678     2012-11-30 23:58:07
```

And I would like to get for each ID number something like this:

```
      Visit_number      duration since last visit
4678        1                    0
            2                    73s
            3                    39s
```

For now I only managed to calculate the number of visits for each ID number with `array.groupby(['IDs']).size()`

Comment: you should supply what you have done, a sample of the data frame and sample output

Comment: A bit vague without data and code

Comment: I edited to make it more clear to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the visit number, you can use groupby and `cumcount`:

```
In [76]: df['Visit_Number'] = df.groupby('IDs').cumcount() + 1
```

Next, for the duration, you can use `diff` for each group:

```
In [77]: df['duration'] = - df.groupby('IDs')['date'].diff()


In [78]: df
Out[78]: 
    IDs                date  Visit_Number  duration
0  4678 2012-11-30 23:59:59             1       NaT
1  4703 2012-11-30 23:59:23             1       NaT
2  4678 2012-11-30 23:58:46             2  00:01:13
3  5803 2012-11-30 23:58:19             1       NaT
4  4678 2012-11-30 23:58:07             3  00:00:39
```

This gives you the difference as a `timedelta`, to have it in seconds and fill the NaN values:

```
In [79]: df['duration'] = df['duration'].astype('timedelta64[s]').fillna(0)

In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
    IDs                date  Visit_Number  duration
0  4678 2012-11-30 23:59:59             1         0
1  4703 2012-11-30 23:59:23             1         0
2  4678 2012-11-30 23:58:46             2        73
3  5803 2012-11-30 23:58:19             1         0
4  4678 2012-11-30 23:58:07             3        39
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

a = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
a.date = a.date.map(lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
for user_id, series in a.sort("date").groupby("id"):
    print user_id, series.date.diff()
```

Outputs:

```
4678 4        NaT
2   00:00:39
0   00:01:13
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
4703 1   NaT
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
5803 3   NaT
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```